# Get 401 (Unauthorized) when login with admin/admin

Tags: angular, jhipster

seperating front-end (angular4) and back-end(jwt, mysql), change SERVER_API_URL to http://localhost:8080/, 
yarn start to launch the front-end successfully, open back_end with idea, set mysql username/password correctly, ./mvnw to launch the monoliths application successfully.
I got an exception:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

It shows /api/account 401 Unauthorized error.

However, registering a new user works well, I can see the user in database.

If I don't separate front-end and back-end, with same settings (jwt, mysql, angular4, etc), everything is ok, so I think there should be something not set correctly.

Could someone help?

Note: java: 1.8, My global angular cli version is:1.5.0 my jhipster version is: 4.11.1 nodejs version is 6.11.3 windows version is: Windows 10, 64 bit, spring boot: 1.5.7.RELEASE

Comment: Seems normal to me as the endpoint for authentication is /api/authenticate not /api/account

Comment: @GaëlMarziou authentication is good cause I can see the jwt token following Bearer, then the front-end send a http get request to 'api/account', however, nowhere I can find the jwt, I think probably this is cause of failure. why not take jwt to back-end?

Comment: You got to debug the angular code to know if the token is stored upon successful authentication and added on account request.

Comment: token is stored in session storage, however, when issue api/account request, the token is not in header, I navigate to the requestIntercept function in auth.interceptor.ts which I think the intercept request, but the function always return in the line 17. while token is retrieved in the line 20.

Comment: See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6813

Comment: just create back-end and front-end from scratch, only change SERVER_API_URL to http://localhost:8080 for front-end, and change mysql user name and password for back-end, api/account still return 401 error, also I found for one login, the front-end issued two requests for /api/authenticate, and two requests for /api/account, strange.